# JavaScript: reading 3 bytes Buffer as an integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Let's say I have a hex data stream, which I want to divide into 3-bytes blocks which I need to read as an integer.

For example: given a hex string `01be638119704d4b9a` I need to read the first three bytes `01be63` and read it as integer `114275`. This is what I got:

```
var sample = '01be638119704d4b9a';
var buffer = new Buffer(sample, 'hex');
var bufferChunk = buffer.slice(0, 3);
var decimal = bufferChunk.readUInt32BE(0);
```

The `readUInt32BE` works perfectly for 4-bytes data, but here I obviously get:

```
RangeError: index out of range
  at checkOffset (buffer.js:494:11)
  at Buffer.readUInt32BE (buffer.js:568:5)
```

How do I read 3-bytes as integer correctly?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you are using node.js v0.12+ or io.js, there is [`buffer.readUIntBE()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuintbe_offset_bytelength) which allows a variable number of bytes:

```
var decimal = buffer.readUIntBE(0, 3);
```

(Note that it's `readUIntBE` for Big Endian and `readUIntLE` for Little Endian).

Otherwise if you're on an older version of node, you will have to do it manually (check bounds first of course):

```
var decimal = (buffer[0] << 16) + (buffer[1] << 8) + buffer[2];
```

Comment: Thanks! Must've missed that `readUIntBE` function. It works perfectly.

Comment: To save a few microseconds: var decimal = (((buffer[0] << 8) + (buffer[1]) << 8) + buffer[2];

Comment: Little endian variant: (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[1] << 8) | bytes[0]

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this, if someone knows something wrong with it, please advise;

```
const integer = parseInt(buffer.toString("hex"), 16)
```

Comment: This worked great for me. I just want text categories to semi randomly get assigned a colour number from a fixed palette of colours.

Comment: Nice! @JoshPeak

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score -3):

you should convert three byte to four byte.

```
function three(var sample){
    var buffer = new Buffer(sample, 'hex');

    var buf = new Buffer(1);
    buf[0] = 0x0;

    return Buffer.concat([buf, buffer.slice(0, 3)]).readUInt32BE();
}
```

You can try this function.