# getting 4 byte from a file and convert it to timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I am facing issue in getting data from a file as a buffer and then converting it into a long sample code is

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.open('24.mkt', 'r', function(status, fd) {
  if (status) {
    console.log(status.message);
    return;
  }
  var buffer = new Buffer(4);
  fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 4, 0, function(err, num) {
    console.log(buffer.values());
  });
});
```

file link - > https://archive.org/download/kamo_24/24.mkt

first 4 bytes contains Timestamp in  Long in  4 Bytes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: reading 3 bytes Buffer as an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911185/javascript-reading-3-bytes-buffer-as-an-integer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use node.js's [Buffer.readInt32BE](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readint32be_offset_noassert) function. It reads 4 bytes in the given order (Big, or Little endian) to a variable, starting at the offset parameter:

```
// Unix timestamp now: 1492079016
var buffer = Buffer.from([0x58, 0xEF, 0x51, 0xA8]);
var timestamp = buffer.readInt32BE(0);

process.stdout.write(timestamp.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`readUInt32BE` and/or `readUInt32LE`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readint32be_offset_noassert) (of `buffer`) to convert buffer values to number.

You may also try to converting a values in a buffer to numeric value using [`node-bigint`](https://github.com/substack/node-bigint) or [`node-bignum`](https://github.com/justmoon/node-bignum) (it's probably overkill for a 4 bytes case but if you need to deal with a bigger numbers it may suit the need), both allow creation from buffer in a similar form (just be aware of options differences):

```
bignum.fromBuffer(buf, opts)
// or
bigint.fromBuffer(buf, opts)
```